# Compilation time for different C++ features

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, compiler-optimization, constexpr

What is the compilation time for different C++ features? I'm interested in choosing the right approach to implement some generic code in my library headers and I'd like to take compilation time for the library users in consideration. Rough and/or relative numbers are just fine.

I'm particularly interested in following cases:

- Adding class specialization
- Adding constexpr function (declaration only)
- Adding the simplest constexpr function (like `{ return true; }`)
- Execution of the simplest constexpr function at compile-time.
- Instantiating a class template
- Instantiating a template alias
- Instantiating a variable template
- Finding the right template class specialization
- Finding the right function via ADL

P.S. Please let's not talk about me doing a premature optimization. Information about compile times will be interesting to C++ developers regardless.

Update: clarified that the code I’m optimizing is in the library headers so its compilation time is definitely important for library users.

Update: rephrased the question to don't inspire opinionated answers.

Comment: Compiler-time depends a *lot* on the actual compiler, version of it, and what options you passed to it (like optimization flags). And usually compilation happens *once* (unless you're working on the library developing it) while it's used often. So for the users of your library compilation time is probably very low on their priority list.

Comment: I am with dude, there are cases where I'll happily accept x10 compilation time if that buys me 10% at runtime

Comment: @oliora Maybe you should also check out The Rule of Chiel, regarding the compile time costs of some of the things listed by you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yep, but this if for the code that is exposed in the interface of the library so it will be included and (re)compiled in multiple translation units.

Comment: @Lorand tnx, I was looking for this one in particular as I saw it some time ago but was not able to find the link.

Comment: IMO, the question has some technical answers, well within the scope of SO.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin oh well. I’ll as this on Reddit. It’s easier to fill tax declaration in the Netherlands than ask anything except simple question on SO.

Comment: We C++ programmers still use Boost and other mastodont libraries, not because their header files are quick to compile (they're quite the opposite, they are messy and complicate and there are a lot of them to include), but because the libraries are good and well-engineered and well-documented. If you want to lower compile-time, then create a single header file with a simple C interface, but it's kind of a waste of all the fun functionality available in C++. :)

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any good source on compilation time for different C++ features?

The original source of this information is `-ftime-report` and `-ftime-trace` compiler options. You can use them to investigate the times you are interested in.

See [Investigating compile times, and Clang -ftime-report](https://aras-p.info/blog/2019/01/12/Investigating-compile-times-and-Clang-ftime-report/) and [time-trace: timeline / flame chart profiler for Clang](https://aras-p.info/blog/2019/01/16/time-trace-timeline-flame-chart-profiler-for-Clang/) for more details.

Comment: That's a valuable answer but probably there are numbers available already so I don't need to do a benchmark by myself.